# How to fix magento shopping cart add to wishlist bug in ie?

Tags: internet-explorer, magento

I am working on a magento project with a custom made sign editor. Everything works fine except for the add to wishlist function in the shopping cart. It works fine on firefox but on ie it does not add the product on the wishlist. I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

I have used firebug on firefox to check if there are some javascript errors but there is none.

Internet Explorer version: 7 & 8
Magento Version: 1.4.1

errors on ie only:

1. Object doesn't support this property
   or method  cart, line 1 character 1
2. Object expected  cart, line 462
   character 1
3. Object doesn't support this property
   or method  signpreview, line 46
   character 2
4. Object doesn't support this property
   or method  updatePost, line 46
   character 2
5. Object doesn't support this property
   or method  signpreview, line 46
   character 2

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: what version of IE? What version of Magento?

Comment: IE 7 & 8 ... I am currently using Magento 1.4.1

Comment: Install the IE developer tools and update your question with any error messages that displays.

Comment: updated the question with the errors that appear only on ie

Comment: please also add what's in those lines where error is reported

Comment: Jordan, what do you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not Magento errors - 'signpreview' and 'updatePost' do not look like anything in the Magento codebase.

Have you swapped over to the default theme and seen if you can add to wishlist? If that works then it is a theming problem, not a products or Magento problem.

Comment: tried the default theme.. the add to wishlist function worked. Thanks for the insight mate.

Comment: Now there is no error on the magento cart page but still i cannot add to wishlist. This time i really don't know what is causing this anymore. But when i use the default theme ... it is working fine. The page was not add to wishlist function was never modified.